# How can I make an embedded Google Audio Player play mp3s from a secure (Password) FTP server?

Tags: html, audio, ftp, embed

I've picked up this code from quicktips on how to embed an audio player on our church's site.  We want to play sermons on it, but the sermons are on an FTP server and when I place address of the files where the url is supposed to go, it doesn't work.

Would there be anyway to amend the code (below) to do that?  Any other work arounds or suggestions?

```
<embed type="application/x-shockwave-flash" src="http://www.google.com/reader/ui/3523697345-audio-player.swf" quality="best" flashvars="audioUrl=ftp://ecclesialatina.asuscomm.com/My_Passport/Webmaster/003_Fr.%20Brancich_Examination%20of%20Conscience_2013_02_17.mp3" width="500" height="27"></embed>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to change the URL to include the username and password, a la:

`ftp://username:password@hostname/path`

However this hase several problems, the most obvious being that it exposes your FTP site's username and password to anyone who care's to look at your site's source, and is therefore a very bad idea. It also might not work unless that particular swf supports it. Even then, it's much better to put the audio on an HTTP server if they are to be publicly accessible.

If you want the files to be accessible only to users with a password, you will need a better, entirely different solution. I suppose you could use Javascript to get the username and password from the user and then use the above solution, but that's not ideal either because they won't get an error message if they enter the wrong password until they try to play something back.

Finally, to reiterate, the best thing is to put your audio on an HTTP server.